# rsync failed to set permissions: operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, cron, rsync

I am trying to replicate my domains group policy from my primary domain controller to my secondary domain controller. When I run the below command which I used from techmint https://www.tecmint.com/samba4-ad-dc-sysvol-replication/ Also understand that this article was written for Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using 18.04 I get;

```
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/var/lib/samba/sysvol/.": Operation not permitted (1)
```

I have SSH setup and that is working fine, and it seems to work with the `--dry-run` attribute. But when I try to run it without `--dry-run` it fails.

Yes I have changed the user to a user that I created and the server to my secondary domain controller

```
rsync -XAavz --chmod=775 --delete-after --progress --stats /var/lib/samba/sysvol/ root@adc2:/var/lib/samba/sysvol/ > /var/log/sysvol-replication.log 2>&1
```

Secondly, if I am able to get this solved I want to create a cron job to run this. Will the cron job run without having to enter the password.

Comment: Does the user account that you created have permission to write to files on the destination machine at ``/var/lib/samba/sysvol/``?

Comment: I just checked on my machine and when I do a "dry run" to a location that I do not have access to, rsync shows that it will work, but in reality it does not work.

Comment: @Gordster In dry run mode, `rsync` will list what it will *try* to do, but doesn't verify that it can actually do the operations.